# listen when a document gets signed (php docusign)

Tags: php, docusignapi

How do I achieve this in docusign?

I'm gonna use php rest api.

-Send dynamic pdf from server.

-Add sign here tab.

-Listen to when the recipient has signed the pdf. (callback?)

-Save the signed pdf to the server.

I don't want to reach the 1000 call limit but I think I will because of the traffic.

Comment: you want "getEnvelopeStatus" they have very good documentation you should consoult

Comment: i think i need this one DocuSign SDK - PHP Connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either have to do as @Dagon suggested, and loop a getEnvelopeStatus to keep checking for signature.

The other way would be to setup Connect and have push notifications for signed envelopes, and somehow use that to trigger the next function in your application.